# Nginx push stream not working

Tags: php, nginx

Nginx push stream not working. Empty answer from /channel/one.

```
 location ~ /pub {
                 push_stream_publisher               admin;
                 push_stream_channels_path    $arg_id;
                 push_stream_store_messages         on;
                 allow          127.0.0.1;
              }

        location ~ /channel/(.*) {
                 push_stream_subscriber         long-polling ; 
                 push_stream_channels_path                 $1;
                 push_stream_longpolling_connection_ttl    10s;   push_stream_last_received_message_time  $arg_time; 
                push_stream_last_received_message_tag     $arg_tag; 

                push_stream_message_template "{\"id\":~id~,\"channel\":\"~channel~\",\"tag\":\"~tag~\",\"time\":\"~time~\",\"text\":~text~}";   

              }
```

PHP:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://127.0.0.1/pub?id='.$channel_id);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($message));
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Javascript - http://pastebin.com/afFmhN4J

What to do? Answer please!

Answer (score 0):

If this is pertaining to HTTP/2, NGINX(v1.9.5) does not support `push-stream` as of yet.